# How to combine multiple ggplots on single page with common x and y labels and common legends?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=c('2006-05-01','2006-05-15', '2006-06-01', '2006-06-15', '2006-06-30'), obs = c(0.23, 0.22, 0.18, 0.16, 0.17), sim=c(0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.14, 0.15), rain=c(0.76,0, 0.12, 0, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(Date=c('2007-05-01','2007-05-15', '2007-06-01', '2007-06-15', '2007-06-30'), obs = c(0.232, 0.230, 0.21, 0.19, 0.15), sim=c(0.22, 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.14), rain=c(0.215,0, 0.88, 0.001, 0.05))
```

I have to make plots with 'Date' as X-axis, 'obs' and 'sim' as primary Y-axis, and 'rain' as inverse bar plot on secondary Y-axis and then combining these plots with common X and Y labels and legends.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
```

```
# Plot 1
        Ratio <- max(c(df1$obs, df1$sim), na.rm = TRUE) / max(df1$rain)
        cor1 <- cor(df1$obs, df1$sim, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
        RainMax <- max(df1$rain,na.rm = TRUE)
        BottomOffset <- 1
        plt1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.Date(Date))) + 
        geom_line(aes(y=obs,color="1")) +
        geom_line(aes(y=sim, color="2")) +
        geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.Date(Date) - 0.1,
        xmax = as.Date(Date) + 0.1,
        ymin = (BottomOffset + RainMax - rain) * Ratio,
        ymax = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio, 
        color = "3"),
        fill = "red", show.legend = FALSE) + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio, color = "red") +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black") +
        labs(x = "Date", color = "") +
        scale_x_date(breaks = round(seq(min(as.Date(df1$Date)), max(as.Date(df1$Date)), by = 15),1))+
        scale_y_continuous(name = expression('Soil moisture, m'^"3"*' m'^"-3"), 
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~ BottomOffset + RainMax  - . / Ratio, name = "Precipitation (inch)"),
        expand = c(0,0)) +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "green", "3" = "red"),
        labels = c("1" = "In-situ", "2" = "Modeled", "3"= "Precipitation")) +
        theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"), 
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 8, angle = 30, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title=element_text(size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
        annotate("text", x=min(as.Date(df1$Date))+30, y=0.05, label= (paste0("R = ",format(round(cor1, 2), nsmall = 2))), size=6) +
        ggtitle('Year = 2006')

# Plot 2

      Ratio <- max(c(df2$obs, df2$sim), na.rm = TRUE) / max(df2$rain)
      cor1 <- cor(df2$obs, df2$sim, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
      RainMax <- max(df2$rain,na.rm = TRUE)
      BottomOffset <- 1
      plt2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=as.Date(Date))) + 
      geom_line(aes(y=obs,color="1")) +
      geom_line(aes(y=sim, color="2")) +
      geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.Date(Date) - 0.1,
      xmax = as.Date(Date) + 0.1,
      ymin = (BottomOffset + RainMax - rain) * Ratio,
      ymax = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio,
      color = "3"),
      fill = "red", show.legend = FALSE) + 
      geom_hline(yintercept = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio, color = "red") +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black") +
      labs(x = "Date", color = "") +
      scale_x_date(breaks = round(seq(min(as.Date(df2$Date)), max(as.Date(df2$Date)), by = 15),1)) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = expression('Soil moisture, m'^"3"*' m'^"-3"), 
      sec.axis = sec_axis(~ BottomOffset + RainMax  - . / Ratio, name = "Precipitation (inch)"),
      expand = c(0,0)) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "green", "3" = "red"),
      labels = c("1" = "In-situ", "2" = "Modeled", "3"= "Precipitation")) +
      theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
      axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
      axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
      axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
      axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"), 
      axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"),
      axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
      axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
      plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 8, angle = 30, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
      axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),  
      axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),
      axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
      legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.title=element_text(size=12),
      legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
      annotate("text", x = min(as.Date(df2$Date))+30, y=0.05, label= (paste0("R = ", format(round(cor1, 2), nsmall = 2))), size = 6) +
      ggtitle('Year = 2007')

# Combining Plot 1 and Plot 2

    ggarrange(plt1, plt2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

## Output

The attached image is the output:
[image]

Issue :

The output has a problem that X-axis got shifted (see red and black horizontal lines for the year 2006). Why are the X-axis shifting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I guess `ggarrange` uses some objects in the environment. When you replaced values of some objects for plot 2, `ggarrange` uses those values for both plots. I assigned different names for objects in plot 1 and plot 2 in the following code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=c('2006-05-01','2006-05-15', '2006-06-01', '2006-06-15', '2006-06-30'), 
                  obs = c(0.23, 0.22, 0.18, 0.16, 0.17), 
                  sim=c(0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.14, 0.15), 
                  rain=c(0.76,0, 0.12, 0, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(Date=c('2007-05-01','2007-05-15', '2007-06-01', '2007-06-15', '2007-06-30'), 
                  obs = c(0.232, 0.230, 0.21, 0.19, 0.15), 
                  sim=c(0.22, 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.14), 
                  rain=c(0.215,0, 0.88, 0.001, 0.05))
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Plot 1
Ratio1 <- max(c(df1$obs, df1$sim), na.rm = TRUE) / max(df1$rain)
cor11 <- cor(df1$obs, df1$sim, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
RainMax1 <- max(df1$rain,na.rm = TRUE)
BottomOffset <- 1

plt1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.Date(Date))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=obs,color="1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=sim, color="2")) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.Date(Date) - 0.1,
                xmax = as.Date(Date) + 0.1,
                ymin = (BottomOffset + RainMax1 - rain) * Ratio1,
                ymax = (BottomOffset + RainMax1) * Ratio1, 
                color = "3"),
            fill = "red", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = (BottomOffset + RainMax1) * Ratio1, color = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Date", color = "") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = round(seq(min(as.Date(df1$Date)), max(as.Date(df1$Date)), by = 15),1))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression('Soil moisture, m'^"3"*' m'^"-3"), 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ BottomOffset + RainMax1  - . / Ratio, name = "Precipitation (inch)"),
                     expand = c(0,0) 
                     ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "green", "3" = "red"),
                     labels = c("1" = "In-situ", "2" = "Modeled", "3"= "Precipitation")) +
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"), 
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 8, angle = 30, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title=element_text(size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  annotate("text", x=min(as.Date(df1$Date))+30, y=0.05, label= (paste0("R = ",format(round(cor11, 2), nsmall = 2))), size=6) +
  ggtitle('Year = 2006')

# Plot 2

Ratio <- max(c(df2$obs, df2$sim), na.rm = TRUE) / max(df2$rain)
cor1 <- cor(df2$obs, df2$sim, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
RainMax <- max(df2$rain,na.rm = TRUE)
BottomOffset <- 1

plt2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=as.Date(Date))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=obs,color="1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=sim, color="2")) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.Date(Date) - 0.1,
                xmax = as.Date(Date) + 0.1,
                ymin = (BottomOffset + RainMax - rain) * Ratio,
                ymax = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio,
                color = "3"),
            fill = "red", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio, color = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Date", color = "") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = round(seq(min(as.Date(df2$Date)), max(as.Date(df2$Date)), by = 15),1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression('Soil moisture, m'^"3"*' m'^"-3"), 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ BottomOffset + RainMax  - . / Ratio, name = "Precipitation (inch)"),
                     expand = c(0,0) 
                     ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "green", "3" = "red"),
                     labels = c("1" = "In-situ", "2" = "Modeled", "3"= "Precipitation")) +
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"), 
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 8, angle = 30, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = 1, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 0, hjust = .5, vjust = 0, face = "plain"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "plain"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title=element_text(size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  annotate("text", x = min(as.Date(df2$Date))+30, y=0.05, label= (paste0("R = ", format(round(cor1, 2), nsmall = 2))), size = 6) +
  ggtitle('Year = 2007')

# Combining Plot 1 and Plot 2
ggarrange(plt1, plt2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: The black horizontal line should overlap with lower X axis corresponding to primary Y axis and red horizontal line should overlap with upper X axis corresponding to secondary Y axis.

Comment: Thanks. The trick worked. Yes, the problem was with the way the ggplot store data. Just changing the objects name works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks guys just had a similar issue here using ggarrange with a combination of ggplots and using different names for objetcs for each plot resolved my problems.